# Deploy ML Model on AWS

Tags: aws

So I have trained a ML Model and I need to use it on AWS to make predictions on newly fed in data on a periodic daily basis, and output this data in the form of an attached email.

However I am fairly new to AWS and am not sure, I don’t know if I should be using SageMaker, EC2 or Lambda for this purpose. Can someone point me in the right way?

I have written a jupyter notebook for this purpose but have also created a .py file as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda and EC2 both can solve your problem. The deployment would be similar that you store the pickled model on S3 bucket and call it in your code from Lambda or Ec2. Lambda is mostly used for even driven things but can be used in your case also. But i will suggest use an EC2 instance on demand (less cost) run your py file at the given time frame and get the model outputs